# invalid BigNumber value (argument="value") Error trying to trigger contract method from ABI

Tags: solidity, transactions, abi, ethers.js, hardhat

From the ABI in a VueJS frontend I'm trying to trigger the following method in my contract:

```
// Payout.sol

function checkStatusAndPay(bytes32 _gameId, int _winner) public notDisabled onlyOwner returns (bool _paid)  {
  // does some checkings and then transfers ethers to registered addresses
  ...
}
```

I'm using this:

```
// payout_service.js

...
const contract = new ethers.Contract(contractAddress, abi, signer);
const transaction = await contract.checkStatusAndPay(id, winner);
...
```

And also tried the same code adding some hardcoded `value`:

```
const transaction = await signerContract.checkStatusAndPay(id, winner, { value: "0.02" });
```

But I keep getting this error:

```
Error: invalid BigNumber value (argument="value", value={"isTrusted":true}, code=INVALID_ARGUMENT, version=bignumber/5.4.1)
```

*Not sure it plays a part here, but I'm using MetaMask wallet

EDIT:

It works fine in tests, I'm using hardhat:

```
describe("Payout", function() {
    before(async function () {
        Payout = await ethers.getContractFactory("Payout");
        [owner, user1, user2, user3] = await ethers.getSigners();

        contract = await Payout.deploy();
    });

      ...
      it("pays prizes to each winner", async function() {
          const tx = await contract.checkStatusAndPay(game, 2);
    
          // check emited events content
          const res = await tx.wait();
    
          // check values in broadcasted events for first winner user1
          expect(res.events[0].args.message).to.equal("Prize sent to user address");
         expect(res.events[0].args.user).to.equal(user1.address);
         expect(res.events[0].args.amount).to.equal(prize1);
    }
}
```

Comment: Hello mate, did you found the issue here? Why not using events to emit the prize instead?

Comment: it was an invalid argument @jdnichollsc. I was passing an empty string when it should have been a BigNum. It was looking OK in the contract, the problem is I forgot to update the ABI in the frontend.